# jquery how to check than mouseleave is on element

Tags: jquery, onmouseover, jquery-hover

Hello i have situation image on the top on the canvas. I need handle then mouseleave canvas except mouse on the image

In the image **black points** is need return **mouse is leave**, **red points** **mouse is not leave**
http://s8.postimg.org/abyzh9glh/Untitled2.png

i try this code but it's doesn't work

```js
    $("#canvas").on("mouseleave", function() {
        if($("#image-on-top").is(':hover')) {
            console.log("mouse is not leave");    
        } else {
            console.log('mouse is leave')    
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image-on-top" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/dreamworks/images/5/54/Edi-szemekkel-mort.png" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 100px">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; z-index: 1"></canvas>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code?

Answer (score 0):

please follow this:

```
$("#image-on-top")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("mouse has entered");
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
   console.log("mouse leaved");
  });
```

Comment: mhmm need to know then mouse leave from canvas place except image cover canvas area

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove "position: absolute" from image tag then below code is helpful for you..

```
    $("#canvas").on("mouseover", function() {
            console.log("mouse is not leave");    
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            console.log("mouse is leave");    
    });
```

Comment: i need this result with image on the top http://s8.postimg.org/abyzh9glh/Untitled2.png

Comment: result should be same but image going to top if you remove position: absolute from image tag you can check https://jsfiddle.net/3hscfaqx/

Answer (score 0):

You can try that as well.

EDIT: A little bit of clarification, [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) is part of CSS and is not a selector in jQuery. That's why it doesn't work when using [:is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

EDIT2: It seems canvas mouse leave is triggered before the image hover. Which means when jquery is executing canvas mouse leave callback, the image is still not set with the hover property. So I changed my code a little bit to handle with the events in this order.

```js
    $(function(){
  var canvasHover = false;
  var imageHover = false;

  $("#image-on-top").on("mouseenter", function(){
    if (!canvasHover) {
      canvasHover = true;
      console.log("mouse isn't leave");
    }
  });
  $("#image-on-top").on("mouseleave", function(){
    canvasHover = false;
    console.log("mouse is leave");
  });


  $("#canvas").on("mouseleave", function() {
    canvasHover = false;
    console.log("mouse is leave");
  });
  $("#canvas").on("mouseenter", function() {
    canvasHover = true;
  });
});
```